# Android camera won't save video

Tags: android, camera, save, recording

The code is from google guide for camera usage, but it won't save the recorded video. I compared this code with another recorders I find here, but nothing works.

Here is the code.
CameraActivity:

```
package test.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import test.com.CameraPreview;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private Button recordButton;
    private Button stopButton;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_capture);

        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = this.getCameraInstance();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        this.stopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
        this.recordButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        this.recordButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.stopButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == this.recordButton.getId()){
            if(prepareVideoRecorder()){
                if(checkCameraHardware(this)) {
                    Log.d("r1", "Started");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    this.mMediaRecorder.start();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        } else if(v.getId() == this.stopButton.getId()){
            Log.d("r1", "Stopped");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            this.mMediaRecorder.stop();
            this.mMediaRecorder.release();
            this.mCamera.lock();
            this.mCamera.stopPreview();
            this.mCamera.release();
        }
    }

    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        try {
            // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
            mCamera.unlock();
            mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

            // Step 2: Set sources
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

            // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
            mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

            // Step 4: Set output file
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

            // Step 5: Set the preview output
            mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            String message = e.getMessage();
            Log.d("tag", e.toString());
        }

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("tag", "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("tag", "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
            mMediaRecorder.release();
            mMediaRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            int cameraType = 1; // front camera
            c = Camera.open(cameraType); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }
}
```

CameraPreview:

```
package test.com;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("tag", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("tag", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.com"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".CameraActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"

            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <!-- configure this activity to use landscape orientation -->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_capture"
        android:text="Capture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_stop"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what you mean by Android camera won't save video.. You are application is not saving video.why you are blaming android for that?

Comment: Of course it is my application fault for not saving videos. I didn't mean to blame Android. That's why I provided code from the application.

Comment: Dear if you cant point out where is your error i think you are not going to get help, because no one is going to look your code line by line and give you a answer, debug the app and find out what is wrong, if you post your problem you ill surly get helped